# Decrypting data in c, using openssl

Tags: c, openssl

In php i use the following functions:

`openssl_get_privatekey` and `openssl_private_decrypt` to decrypt some data.

```
$privatekey = openssl_get_privatekey (file_get_contents("private.key"));
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted_data,$decrypted_data, $privatekey);
```

How can i do the same in c ?

Some suggestions or examples are welcome.

Perry

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this quick demo](http://savetheions.com/2010/01/16/quickly-using-openssl-in-c/) could help you

there are also a bunch of tutorials wich could give you more insight:

[Overview of the API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html)
[Secure handshake](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl2/index.html)
[Providing a secure service](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl3/index.html)